# How to make calculations on pnadas dataframe with multiple index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Suppose I have a multi indexed DataFrame:

```
                      Frequency
occupation    gender           
administrator F              36
              M              43
artist        F              13
              M              15
doctor        M               7
educator      F              26
              M              69
engineer      F               2
              M              65
```

where the first two columns are indexes.
How do I add another column that gives the ratio between F and M?

Comment: I think you unintentionally undid the formatting aspect of a helpful edit. Have a look here to fix the posts appearance to your taste: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape, so for ratio divide columns:

```
df1 = df['Frequency'].unstack()
df1['ratio'] = df1['F'].div(df1['M'])
print (df1)
                  F     M     ratio
administrator  36.0  43.0  0.837209
artist         13.0  15.0  0.866667
doctor          NaN   7.0       NaN
educator       26.0  69.0  0.376812
engineer        2.0  65.0  0.030769
entertainment   2.0  16.0  0.125000
```

If need new column:

```
s = df['Frequency'].xs('F', level=1).div(df['Frequency'].xs('M', level=1))


df['ratio'] = df.index.droplevel(1).map(s)
print (df)
                 Frequency     ratio
administrator F         36  0.837209
              M         43  0.837209
artist        F         13  0.866667
              M         15  0.866667
doctor        M          7       NaN
educator      F         26  0.376812
              M         69  0.376812
engineer      F          2  0.030769
              M         65  0.030769
entertainment F          2  0.125000
              M         16  0.125000
```